# How get data from Relationship tables

Tags: database, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, relationship

I have 2 table in my database that second(orders) table has foreign_key of primary key of first(books) table like these

```
Books 
----+---------+-------------
 id | slug    |    name     |
----+---------+--------------
  1 | math    | mathematics |
----+---------+--------------
  2 | physics | holidays    |
-----------------------------


Orders
----+---------+-------+--------
 id | book_id | count | price  |
----+---------+-------+--------
  1 |    2    |  12   | 100000 |
--------------------------------
```

**I want result like below**

```
result
----+---------+----------+----------+----------+------------------
 id | book_id |   slug   |   name   | order_id | count | price   |
----+---------+----------+----------+-----------------------------
  1 |    2    |  physics | holidays |     1    |   12  | 100000  |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe each product has a price. To that start with relating PRODUCT table to PRICE. 
In cake this is done very easily:

in your Model (`Product.php`)

```
class Product extends AppModel{
   public $hasMany = array('Price');
}
```

in `Price.php`

```
class Price extends AppModel{
   public $hasBelongTo = array('Product');
}
```

in your controller if you query any of these Models the returned array will contain data from both models.

Answer (score 0):

make the relationships as follow

`Product.php`

```
....
public $hasMany = array(
        'Price' => array(
            'className' => 'Price',
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
            'dependent' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'group' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
....
```

`Price.php`

```
.....
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Product' => array(
            'className' => 'Product',
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
....
```

then in your controller use this query

```
$this->Product->find('all',array('contain'=>array('Price')));
```